# download csv generated file with Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I m trying to download a file from a web page using playwright.
The file is a csv file generated from the page to download a list of customers.
So far and with the current code i ve written i download the file but i cannot access it.
I ve done my research and from what i ve found playwright downloads the file momenterily in the downloads of chromium and then it gets deleted when the browser closes.

I ve found some solutions but none seems to work with the way i ve used playwright. I see the words "await" and "const" all the time , but i don't have them in my code.

the code is as follows:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import datetime
from datetime import date,timedelta

link = 'link of the page that has the info'
today= date.today()
dtgb= datetime.timedelta(60) #days_to_go_back
past_date= today-dtgb
past_date= past_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
today= today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=10000)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(link)
    page.click('div [tabindex="4"]')
    page.fill('input#i0116', 'username')
    page.click('input#idSIButton9')
    page.fill('input#i0118', 'password')
    page.click('input#idSIButton9')
    page.click('input#idSIButton9')
    page.goto(link)
    page.is_visible('div.form-body')
    page.fill('input[name="DateFrom"]',past_date)
    page.fill('input[name="DateTo"]', today)
    page.click('button[type=submit]')
    page.click('button[title=export]')
```

after the export button, the file gets downloaded, browser closes and i don't have the file.

the button html is:

```
<button ng-if="$ctrl.results.length" class="btn btn-success ng-scope" title="export" ng-click="$ctrl.createCSV($ctrl.serverResults)" style="">

<i class="fa fa-download">

</i>

</button>
```

any help is welcome.

*ignore the slow _mo=10000, i'm very very new and want everything to go slow so i can see what's going on.

Comment: in code you should add link for this page so we could see page and test code on real page. Without link we can't check it and we have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: totally understandable, but it is the customers of a bank. so you understand why i can't share the site. also you need username and password to reach the point that i face the issue. which, again, i hope you understand that i cannot share. 

then main issue is that i cannot catch the download. the solutions that exist don't help me or i don't know how to implement them.

Comment: if you found solutions which didn't work then you should show them - this way we will not suggest solutions which don't work, or we may see if you use them correctly. But without access to real page it is hard to say what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This here worked for me:

```
with page.expect_download() as download_info:    
    page.goto("Link")
    page.click('xpath=button')
download = download_info.value
path = download.path()
download.save_as("filename.csv")
print(path)

#---------------------
context.close()
browser.close()
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).